# In Java Escaped Json Text to Object conversion makes Text Unescaped

Tags: java, json, escaping, gson, objectmapper

I have an escaped json string and i convert it to object using "new Gson().fromJson(..)" or "new ObjectMapper().readValue(..)".
The problem is that the converter unescape the string which given as parameter.

String str = "{\"abc\":\"1\r\n2\"}";

HashMap v = new Gson().fromJson(str, new HashMap().getClass());

Json String escaped-> {"abc":"1\\r\\n2"}

After conversion unescaped String -> {"abc":"1\r\n2"}

1-)

I want to sanitize json text for header manipulation, though remove '\r','\n' characters. In the input these characters may be escaped or unescaped. So is it true approach to replace it as below before convert to object ?

text.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n|\\\\n|\\\\r","").replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r","");
(first replace escaped crlf characters than replace other crlf characters)

2-)

Is there any other solution for conversion from json to object without unescaping  the string